# How to get data from existing table?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I have a simple table without any dependencies in my database, and a little app which uploads files to storage and saves the urls in this table.

Finally I need a content part, where I can select a file (by name in DDL for example) and save in my content part record table (created via migrations). DDL columns - records from my existing table.

And I want to get access to this data, but I can't :(

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218682/how-to-fetch-table-data-from-database-in-orchard-cms) I tried to do something like that in my custom content part driver:

```
    private readonly IRepository<MyExistingTableModel> _repo;

    public MyCustomContentPartDriver(IRepository<MyExistingTableModel> repo) 
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
```

- `MyExistingTableModel` - model which name and fields identically with DB table.
- `MyCustomContentPartDriver` - my content part, where I want to show data from my table (for selecting file and show it at the view page).

I already read a lot of Orchard CMS tutorials, but I feel that I have missed something simple and important.

Comment: I think you need something like the `medialibrary` services? You can use the existing implementations to upload a file and store the url

Comment: You don't understand my question. I just want to get access to my custom table in orchard module

Comment: There's a lot of missing information here, such as your migration code. Also, you might want to name your table MyExistingTableRecord. Repository is *not* designed to be a generic data access class by the way: it's been designed to provide Content Manager with a uniform way to access content part records. If you have an existing table that has nothing to do with Orchard and does not adhere to its conventions, you'll probably have to grab the nHibernate session and do your own querying.

Comment: Can you give me some example how to grab nHibernate session please? I'm not familiar with it( I found your comment about that: " You can also grab the nHibernate session directly and do arbitrary Hql or even SQL queries from there. There is an example of that in the OrchardPo module. –  Bertrand Le Roy", but I can't find this module

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I found your module here: https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/orchardpo.